# MySQL COUNT() ? Date And Frequency

Tags: mysql, sql

Supposed I have a SQL table that looks like this

[image: image of database table with two columns shown, date and category]

Now I am suppose to do this 'logic' so that I know that on 23/6/2017, the word 'accessories' appeared 2 times and 'tools' appeared 1 time.

I think there is some kind of way to do this is mysql, something along the lines of `COUNT()` and `GROUPBY` but I cannot get the result I want.

Appreciate any guidance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using GROUP BY :

```
SELECT date, category, count(*) as count FROM table_name GROUP BY date, category
```

You have to put every selected columns after group by otherwise it will show query error.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date, category, count(*)
  FORM yourtable
 GROUP BY date, category
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as counting the categories corresponding to each date

```
SELECT   date
         category
         COUNT(*)
FROM     table_name
GROUP BY date, category
```